# Jquery Deferred() upload progress

Tags: backbone.js, jquery-deferred, jqxhr

Does anyone have an example on how to get upload progress from $.Deferred() ?? I want to listen to the progress events like you do with XHR.onprogress

Context:
using backbone.js I'm looking to do something like this.  when the model is saved, I'm uploading a medium sized base64 encoded image.

```
var def = model.save();
def.progress(function(value){
    console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: The jQuery plugin [ajaxForm](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started) will help. You will find it has an `uploadProgress` option, which allows progress to be monitored by way of a callback function. The documentation includes the proviso, "if supported by the browser".

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky, I'm not sure if my code works, just giving you a basic idea. You have to either modify ajax options in `model.save` or [do it globally for all $.ajax calls](https://github.com/englercj/jquery-ajax-progress/blob/master/js/jquery.ajax-progress.js).

This also won't get into deferred, you'll have to use progress callback. After including js from the link that patches ajax options you will be able to use progress callback:

```
model.save({}, {

    progress: function(e) {
        //make sure we can compute the length
        if(e.lengthComputable) {
            //calculate the percentage loaded
            var pct = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;

            //log percentage loaded
            console.log(pct);
        }
        //this usually happens when Content-Length isn't set
        else {
            console.warn('Content Length not reported!');
        }
    }

})
```

Another option would be patching `Model.sync`:

```
ProgressModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    sync: function(method, model, options) {

        function progress(e) {
            model.trigger('progress', e)
        }

        var newOptions = _.defaults({
            xhr: function() {
                var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if(xhr instanceof window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    xhr.addEventListener('progress', progress, false);
                }
                if(xhr.upload) {
                    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progress, false);
                }
                return xhr;
            }
        }, options);

        return Backbone.sync.call(this, method, model, newOptions); 
    }

});

// so now you can listen to progress event on model
model.on('progress', function(e) { })
model.save();
```

Comment: Why you have ``xhr.addEventListener`` and ``xhr.upload.addEventListener`` ? Because of it, the callback associated with progress event is fired twice.

Answer (score -1):

I decided to just create a separate method on the model since I only needed to monitor progress of a POST request.  On my collection, as an "add" handler, I did:

```
onAdd: function (model) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var $def = $.Deferred();

        this.uploadQueue.push($def.promise());

        xhr.open('POST', 'http://myapi/upload-image', true);

        xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
            if (e.lengthComputable) {           
              console.log((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
            }
        }

        xhr.onload = function(e) {
            if (this.status == 201) {
              console.log(this.responseText);
              $def.resolve();
            }
        };

        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(model.toJSON()));

    }
```

Then later in my code I can check if collection.uploadQueue is done to execute other actions. Seems to be working for my needs as of right now.

Comment: I wouldn't take this approach because its not restful and works against Backbone principles. Why do you choose to issue separate ajax request and not use Backbone.sync? Your model won't update after post and trigger no events.

Comment: This "image list" is only used in "create" form of another model (location). I won't need to UPDATE, READ, or DELETE using this model so I figured overwriting sync was overkill and I didn't have time to learn how to minimally overwrite sync.  I created a separte model and collection for the photos so I could manage the list on screen and optimistically upload images when a user selects them.  This reduces perceived wait time when the user actually submits the whole form.  

That being said, I do like your suggestion and I will try and implement it when I refactor my code.  Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, good luck with your project. Regarding file uploads, you may check this answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16275792/329226 where I use Formdata to post models with file attribute.